# how to check which windows features are activated using c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to make a winform application to check if a particular window feature is activated or not? I am using dism command to fetch window features but could not find a way out to check for each window feature by giving its name?
How can I check by just typing a window feature and answer as enabled or disabled ?

Comment: You ought to be able to get something out of System.Management.  Play with the WMI Code Creator utility, look at the Win32_Product class for example.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking at creating a c# app from the DISM command, I would recommend looking into importing the DismApi.dll and creating an api which you can use. By the sounds of it, if you're making an app that handles Windows Feature details, it might be we worth taking this approach.

If you're familiar with PInvoke, you can import the DismApp dll as follows: `[DllImport("DismApi.dll")]` and then call look at this [API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh824738.aspx) for details on the functions you need to invoke.

Alternatively, if you're alright with including 3rd party dlls, then the work's already been done for you. See [ManagedDism api at CodePlex](https://manageddism.codeplex.com/). Your code will then look something like:

```
DismApi.Initialize(DismLogLevel.LogErrors);
using (DismSession session = DismApi.OpenOnlineSession())
{
    foreach (DismFeature feature in DismApi.GetFeatures(session))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(feature.FeatureName + ": " + feature.State);
    }
}
DismApi.Shutdown();
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution,but it is generating an exception saying that it is  not able to find DismApi.dll even when I downloaded it and add reference to it.So I downloaded the source code in .cs format and then build it  and used it but now it shows another exception and says that it can't find DismApi.Initialize in DismApi.dll, and I am again struck.

Comment: You should not be downloading DismApi.dll, it's a system file in `C:\Windows\System32`. I would suggest you forget about the DismApi.dll import and rather download the ManagedDism dll at codePlex. This dll abstracts all the PInvoke API calls for you and you literally just have to reference the dll and use it as in the code snippet. See the codePlex link for more info on the assembly.

Comment: First thing,In codeplex link we have Microsoft.Dism.dll file not ManagedDism.dll.Secondly I downloaded that and used the code snippet,it gave exception stating DismApi.dll not found,so I searched DismApi.dll file in System32 folder but it was not found there,that's why I looked for DismApi.dll.What canI do further ? ?

Comment: I see. What operating system are you using? Also, the DismApi.dll that you downloaded, did you put it into your `%WINDIR%\System32` directory?

Comment: I am using win 7 OS,and yes I put that dll in Windows\System32 as well as  Windows\SYSWOW64.

Comment: I'm not sure why it doesn't pick it up. It should. Perhaps have a look at the CodePlex site and see if other users have had similar experiences or post this question in the discussion forum. The author(s) may be able to assist you better.